# illustrator cs6 : gradient of in each shape gone when unite

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6

the gradient in each of my shapes are gone when I unite them. the combined compound shape just turns into one solid color. for example,

**before unite**

[image: before unite]

**after unite**

[image]

i have searched the internet, and found no answer to my problem. perhaps i did not type in the keywords exactly. please help!

Answer (score 2):

When you `Unite` multiple shapes they become **one** shape. All the individual fills are ignored and a single fill is applied to the united object.

That gradient you have *can't* be accomplished on a single shape as a fill, other than using a gradient mesh. But when using the `Unite` command, meshes aren't generated for you.

A better option may be using a stroke with a gradient applied to the stroke.

[image]

You could then choose `Object > Expand Appearance` on the stroke and a shape with a mesh will be generated.

[image]

Be aware though, a mesh shape is not as easily handled (altered, edited) as a standard shape in many cases. It's often easier to just leave it as a stroke.

<sub>(this was all done in CS6 as well)</sub>